# How to insert json object into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, json, mysqli

There are many examples around which parse the `JSON` and then insert the respective fields into `MySQL` table.

My case is different in a way that I am creating a json at runtime.

my table looks like this:

```
mysql> describe turkers_data;
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id        | char(36) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| sentences | json     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

based on the input received, I build a `json` using `json_encode` method in `php`, which I alredy validated on `jsonlint` and it is of course valid.

example json:

```
{
    "opening": "[\"John arrived at Sally's house to pick her up.\",\"John and Sally were going to a fancy restaurant that evening for a dinner.\",\"John was little nervous because he was going to ask Sally to marry him.\"]",
    "first_part": "[\"aa\",\"bb\"]",
    "first_mid": "[\"Waiter shows John and Sally to their table.\"]",
    "mid_part": "[\"cc\",\"dd\"]",
    "mid_late": "[\"John asks Sally, \\\"Will you marry me?\\\"\"]",
    "last_part": "[\"ee\",\"ff\",\"gg\"]"
}
```

I use following code to insert into mysql table using mysqli

```
$opening = array("John arrived at Sally's house to pick her up.", "John and Sally were going to a fancy restaurant that evening for a dinner.", "John was little nervous because he was going to ask Sally to marry him.");
$mid_early = array("Waiter shows John and Sally to their table.");
$mid_late = array('John asks Sally, "Will you marry me?"');
$json_data->opening = json_encode($opening);
$json_data->first_part = json_encode($jSentence_1);
$json_data->first_mid = json_encode($mid_early);
$json_data->mid_part = json_encode($jSentence_2);
$json_data->mid_late = json_encode($mid_late);
$json_data->last_part = json_encode($jSentence_3);

$data = json_encode($json_data);
echo($data);


$sql = "INSERT INTO turkers_data (id, sentences)
VALUES ($id, $data)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

but it does not work, i get the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"opening":"[\"John arrived at Sally's house to pick her up.\",\"John and Sally w' at line 2
```

I do not know what is wrong. I could not find much information on how to do this, I read that it is not recommended to have `json` data dumped as it is into `mysql` table, but in my case i am unsure of how many sentences  are going to there. Also, I believe this serves the purpose for the time being, I plan to just get that `JSON` from `mysql` back and process the data in `python`.

Also pardon me for using `json`, `JSON`, `MySQL`, `mysql`, I do not know the standard yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having a problem with your SQL insert because you have this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO turkers_data (id, sentences) VALUES ($id, $data)";
```

There is no escaping of quotes on `$data`, and the `$data` is not wrapped in single quotes either.

You should build this as a prepared statement and bind the params which will do all that for you:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO turkers_data (id, sentences) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $id, $data );
$stmt->execute();
```

The above assumes you are using mysqli, and not PDO. If its PDO, this is syntax for PDO method:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO turkers_data (id, sentences) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($id, $data));
```

**EDIT**

Last ditch effort (AND ILL-ADVISED), if your php and mysql do not support prepared statements (it should!), then you can resort to the old method of wrapping and escaping your fields in the sql build string:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO turkers_data (id, sentences) 
        VALUES (
               '". $conn->real_escape_string($id) ."',
               '". $conn->real_escape_string($data) ."'
               )";
```

But this is NOT ADVISED! If at all costs ***you should try to get prepared statements to work***, or upgrade your PHP, or mysqli extensions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think it is PDO, I followed a tutorial from w3schools here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp  If I change my code to what you suggested, I get error as `Error: INSERT INTO turkers_data (id, sentences) VALUES (?, ?)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?, ?)' at line 1`

Comment: That makes me think you are using standard `mysql` methods (not `mysqli`, note the 'i')... ? Can you confirm?

Comment: `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`, it is indeed `mysqli`

Comment: Ok, then its not PDO... mysqli should handle prepare with the ?, ? in it... thats what prepared statements is all about :D

Comment: my bad, I only posted relevant part here and was trying to insert into the other table below somewhere, which was using `$sql` variable, hence there was an error on browser but values are getting inserted, thank you so much!!

Comment: Ah! Good to know. Good luck and have fun coding :)